# Kohana error with utf8.php

Tags: php, kohana

Hi I was making app using kohana and I'm getting this error.

Anyone know how to fix this?

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required  '....../system/utf8/transliterate_to_ascii.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in .......system/classes/kohana/utf8.php on line 149

I was trying changin permission on files and nothing works.

Comment: is system/utf8/transliterate_to_ascii.php file exists?

Comment: Yeah, go to the directory you have Kohana installed to. Then follow the path into system/classes/.... etc and see if that file is there. Should be called transliterate_to_ascii.php